# Best order for water filters to go?

Tags: water-filtration

In my house, I have two [whole house water filter housings](http://amzn.com/B000E78XH6) in the basement, and then a third [**P**oint-**O**f-**U**se filter housing](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Glacier-Bay-Basic-Drinking-Water-Filtration-System-HDGUSS4/205459563) under each sink cabinet.

Currently both basement housings contain 20-micron sediment filters, and each POU housing contains an activated carbon filter.  I am satisfied with the taste of the water, but I notice particulates in my glass.

The plumbing in my house is rather old, and I was *wondering* if the particulates I see might be coming from some sort of buildup within the pipes themselves; rather than from the ground.  (Just a thought, as I have no plumbing experience.)  If that is the case, should I perhaps rearrange my filters so that the sediment filters are in each POU housing, and the carbon filter in the basement?  What do you think?  Also, should I get a smaller micron rating?

Comment: Could the particulates perhaps be bits of carbon from the carbon filter? Tiny black grains of sand...

Comment: Are you using granulated carbon or carbon block filters for POU filtration?

Comment: I was using granulated, but i switched to block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order you have your filters is the correct order. You don't need to waste money on chlorine filters to have better tasting water in your toilets.

If you think you need additional sediment filtration I believe you can find a carbon filter with better sediment filtration to use at each sink. Those housings also take GE brand filters and other filters of that size so look around to see if there's something suitable.

If you can't find anything you may want to consider adding an additional housing at each sink so you can have an independent sediment filter as well as a carbon filter. You can also try replacing your current filter housing with a 2 or 3 stage under counter filtration system that includes a separate spout for filtered water so you don't waste your filter media for things like washing dishes.